# Как осуществить переход на другую страницу в WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Интегрирую верстку на WordPress, и мучает такой вопрос: какую php переменную использовать в статической верстке для перехода на нужную страницу??

```html
<a href="indivi.html">
   Подбробнее
   <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
</a>
```

То есть что должно быть вместо "indivi.html" , чтобы попасть на нужную страницу??
P.S. За ранее извиняюсь за глупый вопрос. Я начинающий верстальщик , и плохо еще знаю WordPress

Answer (score 0):

Обычно ссылка "подробнее" ведет на страницу поста или страницы.

Для этого используют вспомогательную функцию `<?php the_permalink(); ?>`

В вашему случае это будет примерно вот так:

```
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
      Подбробнее
   <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
</a>
```

Однако, все-таки укажите, где именно (какой файл темы) у вас будет использоваться данный кусок кода.